# what is the library used to draw graph in odoo (openerp)

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

i need to khnow the library used in odoo to draw graphs[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parsing of the < graph> views that are created in XML is performed by the web_graph module. Scanning through this module you will find that a Javascript library named d3js is used to render the charts on the client side. This is the library's web page:

http://d3js.org/

Also, http://nvd3.org/ is used which leverages d3js and adds more charts and functionality.